# Get consolidated facebook comments from plugins via API - as in moderation tool

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, plugins, facebook-comments

We have a comments plugin on many of our website pages and would like to be able to retrieve all of the posted comments on the entire site and be able to filter them by the page on which they were posted as the comments are page specific.

All of the comments can be accessed via the url https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments?id={APP_ID} but I need to be able to access this list via the API.

I realise that we can get the comments when we have the url of the page or the object_id of the plugin. The problem is finding all of the object_ids/urls that we have associated on our site in order to use these comment searching methods.
Other than maintaining a list of all urls that we know have the plugin present, is there any way of dynamically maintaining this list through the api?

All pages have the same associated app_id and are in the same domain.

Comment: Were you able to crack this?

Comment: @CoolTechie - no sorry. Had another quick look at the API a month or so ago, but didn't manage to find anything useful.